# WTL. CTabCtrl. Do not erase children windows regions

Tags: c++, wtl

I want to disable blinking.
How to disable erase background for children windows regions in CTabCtrl?

Comment: WTL is lightweight. So all Win API advice applies here as well: handle `WM_ERASEBKGND`, paint accurately, use double buffering.

Comment: I would like to look at double buffering example for WTL.